# IndexError: too many indices for arrayについて

Tags: python, numpy

同様の質問が多々あることは認識しておりますが、動いていたはずのコードが
動作しなくなりましたので、原因がわからずに投稿させていただいております。

SSDの学習プログラムの中で、 以下のエラーが出ており

```
 File "train.py", line 201, in generate
    img, y = self.horizontal_flip(img, y)
  File "train.py", line 117, in horizontal_flip
    y[:, [0, 2]] = 1 - y[:, [2, 0]]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

プログラム記述としては以下になっています。

```
200                     if self.hflip_prob > 0:
201                         img, y = self.horizontal_flip(img, y)
```

---

```
114     def horizontal_flip(self, img, y):
115         if np.random.random() < self.hflip_prob:
116             img = img[:, ::-1]
117             y[:, [0, 2]] = 1 - y[:, [2, 0]]                                                                       
118         return img, y
```

本プログラム少し前まで一度は動作していたのですが、
・学習用データを更新した
・何らかのミスタッチでtrain.pyを書き換えた
・Pythonのバージョン（変更した認識はありませんが）
などなど、原因特定できず困っております。
情報足りないかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 変数 y (numpy.array)の次元数(shape)が異なっているのではないかと思われます。116行目と117行目の間に `print y.shape` を入れて確認すると良いかと。

Comment: 早々のフォローありがとうございます。不明なのは、一度動いていたはずのコードということで、データ依存で動作が異なることがあるかなどです。

Comment: 入力データによって y の shape が変化しているという事かと思います。掲示されているコードの断片からはそれ以上の事は分かりませんね。。。

Answer (score 1):

`y[:, [0, 2]] = 1 - y[:, [2, 0]]`においてエラーが発生していますが、エラーコード`IndexError: too many indices for array`は、スライスのインデックスの次元が配列の次元よりも大きいということで、要するに変数`y`は2次元以上の`ndarray`である必要があるのですが、実際には1次元以下であるということです。

問題は、質問に提示されるコードより前に発生していると思われ、「情報足りないかもしれません」と書いてあるとおりです。

Comment: フォローありがとうございます。学習データの方に問題があり、次元がマッチしない情報を出すような内容になっていました。ありがとうございます。